# Exceptions and showing error messages in GUI

Tags: java, exception, model-view-controller, error-handling

Say I have a program containing a view, a controller and a model.

[image: SSD Diagram of mvc]

How do I show the error message that addSomething() in the model generates, in the view?

Comment: That depends a whole lot on the technical details of your MVC framework. How does the conroller order changes on the View in general? Does the View subscribe to events from the Controller? Because that would be the best practice. In that case you'd just need to define an `error` event.

Comment: In my case, it's a Java Swing application, with a jFrame calling a method in the controller, that then calls a method in the model. So it's a very simple scenario. I tried to type the question as general as possible, but I can see with all the mvc frameworks out there, that it maybe was the wrong approach.

Comment: One thing that's potentially bad in your design is that you are using synchronous calls to controller and then model. If everything is RAM-based and no serious calculation is done, that's acceptable, but it does create a strong coupling between the layers.

Comment: How could I make it asynchronous in Java? Is there a specific class I would use to help me?

Comment: You would design everything around an event model, where your GUI just publishes an event that says "user requested to do *something*". By itself this doesn't mean computing got asynchronous, but you get loose coupling between view and controller. Asynchrony would be achieved if the event publishing method just enqueued the event, and the queue was consumed from another thread (this could be easily accomplished by modeling the event as a task for an Executor Service). The task which handles the event would then enqueue events to Swing's event queue, and View would react to them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the java.awt.Label? Assuming of course this use using Swing? Some sudo code may look like

```
Label myLabel; //Wired up to your jFrame
myLabel.setVisible = false; //Set the label to be invisible 
String errorStr;
try{
    addSomething()
}
catch(Exception e){
    errorStr = e.printStackTrace();
    myLabel.setVisible = true; //show the label since we have a string value to pass to it
}
myLabel.text = errorStr;
//more code goes here.
```

Keep in mine that's some simple sudo code, but that should get you started in the right direction.